# \vspace doesn't work

Tags: vspace

This is a very simple document. Yet, `\vspace` doesn't work:

```
\begin{titlepage}
Dies ist ein Test.
\vspace{5cm}
Dies ist ein Test.
\end{titlepage}
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: If you insert a blank line imediately before or after the `\vspace` command, you will get the expected result.

Comment: Why is this nowhere documented?

Comment: You have read all of these books in "[What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/16967)"?

Comment: It still doesn't work when i delete the first line.

Comment: It's not a bug...it's a feature!  Welcome to the site.

Comment: @user2762996 It is documented in the official manual.

Answer (score 12):

Quoting from Leslie Lamport’s *LaTeX: A Document Preparation System*, p. 216,:

> `\vspace {`*len*`}`
>   `\vspace*{`*len*`}`
>
> Add a vertical space of length *len*.
>   If the command appears in the middle of a paragraph,
>   then the space is added after the line containing it.

This is what happens in your case.

**Edit:** The quotation continues:

> The space produced by `\vspace` is removed if it falls at a page break;
>   that produced by `\vspace*` is not.

Now, this is exactly the case if you remove the first line “Dies ist ein Test.”: indeed, the `titlepage` environment forces a page break at its beginning.  So, if you want the space not to disappear there, you must use `\vspace*`.